# Simple Screen Grabber in Ruby, Selenium Webdriver throws Errors

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I`m having problem with implementing a simple screen grabber.
The basic script is below:

```
require 'selenium-webdriver' 

width = 1024 
height = 728 

@websites = Array.new

file = open('websites.txt')

file.each_line { |line| @websites.push line }

@websites.each do |website|
    d = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
    puts "Now going to:"+ " #{website}"
    d.navigate.to website 
    d.execute_script %Q{ 
    window.resizeTo(#{width}, #{height}); 
    } 
    d.save_screenshot("#{website.gsub('http://', '')}"+".png") 
    d.quit 
    sleep 10
end
```

The exception that selenium throws:

```
ruby keepwatch.rb
Now going to: http://www.example.com/
/Users/Big_Bird/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.31.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver_extensions/takes_screenshot.rb:18:in `initialize': No such file or directory - www.example.com/ (Errno::ENOENT)
.png
    from /Users/Big_Bird/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.31.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver_extensions/takes_screenshot.rb:18:in `open'
    from /Users/Big_Bird/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.31.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver_extensions/takes_screenshot.rb:18:in `save_screenshot'
    from keepwatch.rb:29:in `block in <main>'
    from keepwatch.rb:22:in `each'
    from keepwatch.rb:22:in `<main>'
```

I'll appreciate any help I can get on this matter.

Comment: Can you post a sample of websites.txt?

Answer (score 2):

Try to add path to file and remove / from the end (www.example.com/). If that does not work, try removing all points except the point between the file name and extension.

For example - d.save_screenshot("./screenshot.png")